# How to Increase an integer value by 1 in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So, I have the following code:

```
<div class="total_number">                              
    <?php echo $number_count;?>                       
</div>
```

Where `$number_count` is just integer number (ex, 10 or 9).

Now, when the `.total_number` is clicked, I want to increase the number by 1.

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.total_number', function(e) {    
    //increase the number
});
```

I am bit confused on how to write the js for this.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can:

- Get the div content with the `.html` function
- Parse it to `int` with the `.parseInt` function
- Sum `1` to the result
- Finally change the html content of the div with the `.html` function

In one line:

```
$(this).html( parseInt( $(this).html() ) + 1 );
```